# Does groupby automatically group over all non numeric columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample of a dataset below (only showing the first couple rows but there are 193 rows):

```
country,beer_servings,spirit_servings,wine_servings,total_litres_of_pure_alcohol,continent
Afghanistan,0,0,0,0.0,Asia
Albania,89,132,54,4.9,Europe
Algeria,25,0,14,0.7,Africa
Andorra,245,138,312,12.4,Europe
Angola,217,57,45,5.9,Africa
Antigua & Barbuda,102,128,45,4.9,North America
...
```

When I run this: `drinks.groupby('continent').head()`

I get back a dataframe with 30 rows. But in those 30 rows I still have duplicate names for the `continent`. For example in the image below you can see that `Europe` is repeated two times (at rows 1 and 3):

[image]

I am not able to understand why I am still having two rows with the same continent when I grouped by continent originally?

In this case is the `groupby` operation also grouping by the `country` even though I never specified it in the `groupby` function? Since I know in SQL you are supposed to use an aggregate function like `max`, `min`, `sum`, etc. But in this case I don't have to pass in an aggregate function and I get the result above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No!

What is happening is that `head` is a method on the `groupby` object and behaves a little differently than `pd.DataFrame.head`.

What the the [**`groupby` version of `head`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) does is returns the head of each group.

So we can see this more clearly by passing `1` to the `head` method and see it return the first row of each subset

```
df.groupby('continent').head(1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`drinks.groupby('continent').head([n=5])` returns the first `n` rows from each group, but then **reorders them by the original index**. Try calling `drinks.groupby('continent').head(1)`, and you will see that only one country from each continent is included in the result.

Comment: But indirectly it is still grouping by `continent` and `country` when I don't pass in any parameter to head correct? Since there are multiple rows with the continent as `Europe`.

Comment: When you do not pass any parameters to `head`, it uses the default value of `n=5`. It extracts the first 5 rows from each continent, but then orders them by the original index before displaying the result.

Comment: Oh ok I see now. Thank you.